# most efficent way to compare a form value and database value

Tags: sql, database, magento

I have created a single table in my Magento database, this table has no connections to any of the magento tables. I have created a form that allows a user to put information into that table.

Within that table there is a column that must hold a unique value, I have set that column to only allow unique values in it.

What i'm currently doing is simply passing the data in without checking if the value is unique and getting a 'Integrity constraint violation' message shown on my screen.

What I want to do is before trying to pass data to that table is check that the value the user is trying to enter does not already exists within the table and if it does, pass them on to the relevant page, or is it possible to use that 'Integrity constraint violation' to then pass the user onto the relevant page?

I know how to compare values using raw php and mysql code, but after reading up on Magento I see that using sql queries are discouraged so I considered creating an array which will hold all rows from that column then comparing that array against the users inputted data, but this seems like a big waste of resources especially as the database grows.

How would be the best way to achieve this?

If this is a situation that a sql query would be acceptable to be run directly on the table, where do I look in the code to find that function I need to use?

Comment: If you do not rely on models and resource model, using direct sql queries may not be a real problem and may save your time.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, following can be possible solutions:

> 1. Either use a stored procedure in the database to check if the value exists in the table. If it does simply return a message to be trapped
>      and corresponding action to be performed in the front end.
> 2. use a hashmap construct (map collection) which will cut the processing time to minimum in the front end.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It definatly gives me something to think about and look into as I wouldn't have a clue how to use those. I was hoping it would be a bit more basic, but I will start researching